# The process cannot access the file 'file path' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#

I know this has been asked multiple times before but I still can't find what's the cause of this. I'm sure the file isn't being used by an external program, so the cause must be in this method. The error occurs in the line where I initialize StreamWriter object for the second time (int the for loop).

```
static void WriteData(PeopleContainer people)
    {
        var file = new StreamWriter(File.Open(Directory + Output1, FileMode.Create), Encoding.GetEncoding(1257));
        for (int i = 0; i < people.SeenByEveryone.Count; i++)
        {
            Film film = people.SeenByEveryone.GetFilm(i);
            file.WriteLine("{1}{0}{2}{0}{3}{0}{4}{0}{5}{0}{6}{0}{7}{0}{8}", CsvSeparator, film.Title, film.Year, 
                           film.Director, film.Genre, film.Company, film.BoxOffice, film.Actors[0], film.Actors[1]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < people.Count; i++)
        {
            Person person = people.GetPerson(i);
            string path = String.Format("{0}Rekomendcija_{1}_{2}.csv", Directory, person.FirstName, person.LastName);

            file = new StreamWriter(File.Open(path, FileMode.Create), Encoding.GetEncoding(1257));
            for (int j = 0; j < person.RecomemdedFilms.Count; j++)
            {
                Film film = person.RecomemdedFilms.GetFilm(j);
                file.WriteLine("{1}{0}{2}{0}{3}{0}{4}{0}{5}{0}{6}{0}{7}{0}{8}", CsvSeparator, film.Title, film.Year,
                               film.Director, film.Genre, film.Company, film.BoxOffice, film.Actors[0], film.Actors[1]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look at doing [string.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead of formatting a string like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should dispose your Stream.Writer when you are finished with it.

```
        using(var file = new StreamWriter(File.Open(Directory + Output1, FileMode.Create), Encoding.GetEncoding(1257)))
        {
            //your loop
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < people.Count; i++)
        {

            using(file = new StreamWriter(File.Open(path, FileMode.Create), Encoding.GetEncoding(1257)))
            {
                 // other loop
            }
        }
```

**EDIT:**

Like @enkryptor mention: if you want all the recommended films to be in your file in the second loop, you should use `StreamWriter` **not** in your loop. Also you should put `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`

```
using(file = new StreamWriter(File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate), Encoding.GetEncoding(1257)))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < people.Count; i++)
    {

          file.WriteLine(...//your stuff)         
    }
}
```

Comment: From the error it seems that the people collection is not unique. If you reopen the file with FileMode.Create previous file will bee overwritten

Comment: @enkryptor it depends what he wants to do, for some reason his FileMode is Create always if we wants to put everything in the the file mode should be OpenOrCreate

Comment: Also antiviruses don't like when a program reopens single file too many times. It looks like a suspicious activity for them. The best solution here is to store Dictionary of StreamWriters, then close them after write operation is conpletely done

Comment: For some reason it's working the way it is. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @PoVa you can mark the answer for correct if help you !